# Error in webpack settings, How to set webpack 5 in Next.js?

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am trying to configure webpack5 in next.config.js as instructed in nextjs documentation. But things not working.

In next.config.js I have the following:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
    env: {
        SERVER_URL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
        SERVER_URL_V: process.env.SERVER_URL_V,
        FILE_UPLOAD_SERVER_URL: process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_SERVER_URL,
        FILE_URL: process.env.FILE_URL,
        FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE: process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE || 10,
    },
    images: {
        domains: ["via.placeholder.com", "placeimg.com"],
    },
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  }
});
```

*Having this error:*
[image]

Comment: When you start up dev, does it show that webpack5 is being used in the console?

Comment: Yes, it does... it starts with 
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /home/jamil/Dev/gscs-audit-frontend/.env
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option not enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

Comment: It is saying that the option is not enabled, so there's a misconfig somewhere in your next.config.js file.